# Updating variables

Tags: java, android, variables

I'm trying to make a little quiz app. Somehow I've some trouble to create a toast with the incorrect answers of the quiz. It doesnt update the global variable correctly. Also I'd like to know how to update the variable with just the actual wrong numbers. Atm it shows for example "Something is wrong, check question nr.: 3 4 3 4 3 4" if the "Check My Answers" Button is clicked multiple times.

My activity_main looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/two" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.android.gtaquizapp.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            style="@style/HeaderTextViewFormat"
            android:text="@string/QuestionOne" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/question_one_answer_box"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:maxLength="16"
            android:maxLines="1" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/HeaderTextViewFormat"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/QuestionTwo" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/question_two_radio_group"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question_two_radio_one"
                style="@style/RadioAndCheckBoxStyle"
                android:text="@string/AnswerTwo_one" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question_two_radio_two"
                style="@style/RadioAndCheckBoxStyle"
                android:text="@string/AnswerTwo_two" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question_two_radio_three"
                style="@style/RadioAndCheckBoxStyle"
                android:text="@string/AnswerTwo_three" />

        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            style="@style/HeaderTextViewFormat"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/QuestionThree" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question_three_checkbox_one"
            style="@style/RadioAndCheckBoxStyle"
            android:text="@string/AnswerThree_one" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question_three_checkbox_two"
            style="@style/RadioAndCheckBoxStyle"
            android:text="@string/AnswerThree_two" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question_three_checkbox_three"
            style="@style/RadioAndCheckBoxStyle"
            android:text="@string/AnswerThree_three" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question_three_checkbox_four"
            style="@style/RadioAndCheckBoxStyle"
            android:text="@string/AnswerThree_four" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/HeaderTextViewFormat"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/QuestionFour" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/question_four_radio_group"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question_four_radio_one"
                style="@style/RadioAndCheckBoxStyle"
                android:text="@string/AnswerFour_one" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question_four_radio_two"
                style="@style/RadioAndCheckBoxStyle"
                android:text="@string/AnswerFour_two" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question_four_radio_three"
                style="@style/RadioAndCheckBoxStyle"
                android:text="@string/AnswerFour_three" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question_four_radio_four"
                style="@style/RadioAndCheckBoxStyle"
                android:text="@string/AnswerFour_four" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            style="@style/HeaderTextViewFormat"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/QuestionFive" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id = "@+id/question_five_radio_group"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question_five_radio_two"
                style="@style/RadioAndCheckBoxStyle"
                android:text="@string/AnswerFive_two" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+i`enter code here`d/question_five_radio_one"
                style="@style/RadioAndCheckBoxStyle"
                android:text="@string/AnswerFive_one" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:onClick="checkAnswersMethod"
            android:text="@string/CheckAnswersButtonText" />

    </LinearLayout>
</TableLayout>
```

And my MainActivity looks like this:

```
package com.example.android.gtaquizapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.example.android.gtaquizapp.R.id.question_four_radio_four;
import static com.example.android.gtaquizapp.R.id.question_four_radio_three;
import static com.example.android.gtaquizapp.R.id.question_two_radio_three;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/**
 *Global variables are updated by the methods answerOne();, answerTwo(); answerThree(); answerFour(); answerFive();
 */
private boolean questionOne = false;
private boolean questionTwo = false;
private boolean questionThree = false;
private boolean questionFour = false;
private boolean questionFive = false;
private String checkedTextNotAllCorrect = "Something is wrong, check question nr.:";

/**
 * This method is executed if the button "Check My Answers" is clicked.
 * It creates a toast with the String checkedTextAllCorrect if all answers are correct or with checkedTextNotAllCorrect if something is wrong
 */
public void checkAnswersMethod(View v) {
    String checkedTextAllCorrect = "Everything is correct, great job!";
    answerOne();
    answerTwo();
    answerThree();
    answerFour();
    answerFive();

    if (questionOne & questionTwo & questionThree & questionFour & questionFive) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), checkedTextAllCorrect, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), checkedTextNotAllCorrect, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Updates the global variable questionOne if the answer was correct
 * Updates the global variable checkedTextNotAllCorrect with the questions number if the answer was not correct
 */
public void answerOne() {
    EditText questionOneAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.question_one_answer_box);
    if (questionOneAnswer.getText().toString().equals("Grand Theft Auto")) {
        questionOne = true;
    } else {
        checkedTextNotAllCorrect += " 1";
    }
}

/**
 * Updates the global variable questionTwo if the answer was correct
 * Updates the global variable checkedTextNotAllCorrect with the questions number if the answer was not correct
 */
public void answerTwo() {
    RadioGroup questionTwoRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.question_two_radio_group);
    int radioButtonID = questionTwoRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    switch (radioButtonID) {
        case R.id.question_two_radio_one | question_two_radio_three:
            checkedTextNotAllCorrect += " 2";

        case R.id.question_two_radio_two:
            questionTwo = true;
    }
}

/**
 * Updates the global variable questionThree if the answer was correct
 * Updates the global variable checkedTextNotAllCorrect with the questions number if the answer was not correct
 */
public void answerThree() {
    CheckBox checkBoxOne = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.question_three_checkbox_one);
    CheckBox checkBoxTwo = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.question_three_checkbox_two);
    CheckBox checkBoxThree = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.question_three_checkbox_three);
    CheckBox checkBoxFour = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.question_three_checkbox_four);

    if (checkBoxTwo.isChecked() & checkBoxThree.isChecked() & checkBoxFour.isChecked() & !checkBoxOne.isChecked()) {
        questionThree = true;
    } else {
        checkedTextNotAllCorrect += " 3";
    }

}

/**
 * Updates the global variable questionFour if the answer was correct
 * Updates the global variable checkedTextNotAllCorrect with the questions number if the answer was not correct
 */
public void answerFour() {
    RadioGroup questionFourRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.question_four_radio_group);
    int radioButtonID = questionFourRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    switch (radioButtonID) {
        case R.id.question_four_radio_one:
            questionFour = true;

        case R.id.question_four_radio_two | question_four_radio_three | question_four_radio_four:
            checkedTextNotAllCorrect += " 4";
    }

}

/**
 * Updates the global variable questionFive if the answer was correct
 * Updates the global variable checkedTextNotAllCorrect with the questions number if the answer was not correct
 */
public void answerFive() {
    RadioGroup questionFiveRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.question_five_radio_group);
    int radioButtonID = questionFiveRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    switch (radioButtonID) {
        case R.id.question_five_radio_one:
            checkedTextNotAllCorrect += " 5";

        case R.id.question_five_radio_two:
            questionFive = true;

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For methods `answerTwo()` , `answerFour()` and `answerFive()` you are using `switch-case` without `break` statements which is causing the issue.

Add `break` statement after each `case` for switch. See example below for `answerTwo()`.

```
public void answerTwo() {
RadioGroup questionTwoRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.question_two_radio_group);
int radioButtonID = questionTwoRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

switch (radioButtonID) {
    case R.id.question_two_radio_one | question_two_radio_three:
        checkedTextNotAllCorrect += " 2";
        break;
    case R.id.question_two_radio_two:
        questionTwo = true;
        break;
}
```

}

Do the same for other methods in which you have used `switch-case`.

Comment: Thank you. Now I've just the problem that the toast message is getting bigger everytime after pressing the button to check the answers. I've added `checkedTextNotAllCorrect = "Something is wrong, check question nr.:";` to the checkAnswersMethod to reset the sentence to its default before it gets updated through the methods. But this doesn't work, why?

Comment: add `checkedTextNotAllCorrect = "Something is wrong, check question nr.:";` after if-else in `checkAnswersMethod()` method

Comment: Thank you it works now. But why exactly does it works if I add it after the if-else statement and not if I add it before the if-else statement?